# argparse allowing long option names to be truncated: Is this a bug? How can I disable it?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I encountered a very weird problem with `argparse` when parsing the command line arguments.
Specifically, even if I don't provide the full argument name, it doesn't raise any errors.
When the argument name is `--long_string`, still `--long_s` is considered to be a valid argument. I'm using **Python version 3.9.7**. Consider the following simple code.

```
import argparse

def _parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--long_string",
                        required=True,
                        type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = _parse_arguments()
    print (args)
```

When I ran the following command in the bash shell:

```
python ex01.py --long_stri="A"
```

The result is as follows:

```
Namespace(long_string='A')
```

My expectation is that since the required `long_string` argument was not provided, it should have raised an exception.

As an another example, when I ran the following command:

```
python ex01.py --long_string="A" --lon="B"
```

The result is as follows:

```
Namespace(long_string='B')
```

This is very confusing. Then it means that any substring which is the prefix of the expected command line arguments will be considered as a valid command line argument. This may cause an unexpected bug in some cases.

Could anyone explain the reason and suggest how to avoid such an issue?

Comment: That's the intended default behaviour, and can be configured if you don't want it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching. It's only an error if there's an _ambiguity_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Thanks for your comment. Then how can we disable this behavior?  Additionally, in the second example of running (python ex01.py --long_string="A" --lon="B"), even though it is ambiguous, it still doesn't raise an error. Oh, it seems that I need to add " allow_abbrev=False".

Comment: Read the docs? And it's unambiguous as far as which argument you wanted the value to go to, there's no e.g. `--london` to confuse it with.

Comment: Given the constraints on its operation (taking place only when there _is_ exactly one possibility), can you describe any _specific, actual_ case where this "can cause an unexpected bug"?

Comment: By a mistake, I typed the argument name incorrectly, which is a typo of the correct one. But by a chance, it happens to be the same as the prefix of another augment. In this case, raising an exception may be better. In the future, I will probably always use " allow_abbrev=False".

Comment: New enough python versions have a 'allow_abbreviation' parameter.  Check the docs.  I don't recall the exact version and wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `argparse` docs:

```
allow_abbrev
Normally, when you pass an argument list to the parse_args() method of an ArgumentParser, it recognizes abbreviations of long options.

This feature can be disabled by setting allow_abbrev to False:

>>>
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', allow_abbrev=False)
>>> parser.add_argument('--foobar', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foonley', action='store_false')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foon'])
usage: PROG [-h] [--foobar] [--foonley]
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: --foon
New in version 3.5.
```